# Which facebook api allows me to interact with Facebook Marketplace?

Tags: facebook

Hey!
I´m trying to figure out which is the best Facebook api for interacting with Facebook Marketplace. I need to automatically post in my own account from a third part application.

I´m searching the web for a specific api for this, but I couldn´t find any yet. What do you guys think is best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there is no Facebook API to access the Marketplace. The Marketplace parts of the old REST API was deprecated in early 2010 and the new Graph API does not have Marketplace functionality.